# Is the PACELC Theorem a Theorem or a conjecture

Tags: database, distributed-computing, distributed-system, cap

Recently, I read D. J. Abadi article [Consistency Tradeoffs in Modern Distributed Database System Design](http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/dna/papers/abadi-pacelc.pdf) explaining the existence of a consistency-latency trade-off in database systems also known as PACELC. Quoting Wikipedia article about the [PACELC Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PACELC_theorem):

> It states that in case of network partitioning (P) in a distributed
>   computer system, one has to choose between availability (A) and
>   consistency (C) (as per the CAP theorem), but else (E), even when the
>   system is running normally in the absence of partitions, one has to
>   choose between latency (L) and consistency (C).

The IEEE Computer article does not show any proof nor claims that PACELC is a Theorem. So, my question is: Is the PACELC a Theorem or a conjecture?